# slide up with transform3d with relative property

Tags: css

I am trying to slide up an element on a button click with css property `transfrom: translate3d(0,-100px,0);` but the element below having relative position is no sliding up with that element leaving some space.

**First Container CSS Properties:**

```
.setupContainer {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(23, 29, 97, 0.9);
color: #FFF;
cursor: default;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

**Second Container Css Properties:**

```
.top_header {
position: relative;
width: 98%;
height: 165px;
background: #FFF;
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
clear: both;
top: 1%;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 3px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #8CC5A7;
}
```

Comment: could you provide the piece of html markup causing the issue as well (so we can tailor our answers accordingly?)

Comment: the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element.

Comment: @jbutler483 The two containers HTML is as follows:

`<div class="setupContainer">
    <div class="sg_btn"> <span> Close </span> </div>
</div>
 
    <!--top whie header-->
    <div class="top_header" style="height:225px;"> </div>`
On clicking .sg_btn the parent container moves up but leaves the adjusting container as it is.

Comment: Got the issue fixed by changing the relative position of First container to absolute position.